# lua - Read .raw file

Tags: lua, torch

I am trying to read a .raw image file into lua but currently I am having little success converting the binary to integers. I am trying the following code;

```
f = io.open(filePath,"r")
f:read("*all")
```

which yields a big binary print including lines like the below;

```
?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0?0??
```

Comment: To add, I know that the file contains shorts.

Comment: Raw files typically use 12 or 14 bits to represent each pixel (per colour channel). Do you have the option to pre-process into a more compact form?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your binary data read, assuming there's only shorts:

```
local f = io.open("data.bin","rb")
local data = f:read("*all")
f:close()

for i=1,data:len(),2 do
    print(data:byte(i)+256*data:byte(i+1))
end
```

In short - you read it byte-by-byte and reconstruct numeric values.
You will need to now if your data is LSB or MSB. My sample assumes LSB.

Answer (score 2):

If the whole file is made of shorts, you can use the torch [Storage](https://github.com/andresy/torch7-split/blob/master/rocks/torch/doc/storage.md#__torch.StorageMap) as follows

`local f = torch.ShortStorage("data.raw")`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read this section in the manual about binary files:

> The simple model functions io.input and io.output always open a file in text mode (the default). In Unix, there is no difference between binary files and text files. But in some systems, notably Windows, binary files must be opened with a special flag. To handle such binary files, you must use io.open, with the letter `b´ in the mode string.

Source: http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.2.html

Answer (score 0):

.raw files are in a other format. read it with binary or found out the correct format of the image. decode it.